# In python, how to correctly use `colorbar` and `pcolormesh`?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Here is my code,

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable # colorbar
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm # 3D surface color
import numpy as np
```

```
data1 = np.random.rand(10, 12)
data2 = np.random.rand(10, 12)
data3 = data1 - data2

vmin = min([data1.min(), data2.min(), data3.min()])
vmax = max([data1.max(), data2.max(), data2.max()])
fig, (ax_1, ax_2, ax_error) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 6))

ax_1.set_ylabel('x')
mesh_1 = ax_1.pcolormesh(data1.T, cmap = cm.coolwarm)

ax_2.set_ylabel('x')
mesh_2 = ax_2.pcolormesh(data2.T, cmap = cm.coolwarm)

mesh_error = ax_error.pcolormesh(data3.T, cmap = cm.coolwarm)
ax_error.set_ylabel('x')
ax_error.set_xlabel('t')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax_2)
cax_val = divider.append_axes("right", size="2%", pad=.1)

fig.colorbar(mesh_2, ax=[ax_1, ax_2, ax_error], cax=cax_val)
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

and it produces an image

[image]

However, what I expect is that it produces the picture below

[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestion!

Comment: The rightmost vertical line of the second image **is** vertically aligned with the rightmost lines of the other two graphs. You is wrong with the output?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Hi, I've changed the question description to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from @JodyKlymak, I finally solved the problem. The keypoint lies in using `shrink`, i.e. `fig.colorbar(mesh_2, ax=[ax_1, ax_2, ax_error], shrink=0.3)`. Here is the solution

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm # 3D surface color
import numpy as np
```

```
data1 = np.random.rand(10, 12)
data2 = np.random.rand(10, 12)
data3 = data1 - data2

fig, (ax_1, ax_2, ax_error) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 6))

mesh_1 = ax_1.pcolormesh(data1.T, cmap = cm.coolwarm)
mesh_2 = ax_2.pcolormesh(data2.T, cmap = cm.coolwarm)
mesh_error = ax_error.pcolormesh(data3.T, cmap = cm.coolwarm)

fig.colorbar(mesh_2, ax=[ax_1, ax_2, ax_error], shrink=0.3)
plt.show()
```

and it produces

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`tight_layout` doesn't help with this problem, unfortunately.  No `tight_layout` and no `axes_grid` works fine:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm # 3D surface color
import numpy as np

data1 = np.random.rand(10, 12)
data2 = np.random.rand(10, 12)
data3 = data1 - data2

fig, (ax_1, ax_2, ax_error) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 6))

mesh_1 = ax_1.pcolormesh(data1.T, cmap = cm.coolwarm)
mesh_2 = ax_2.pcolormesh(data2.T, cmap = cm.coolwarm)
mesh_error = ax_error.pcolormesh(data3.T, cmap = cm.coolwarm)

fig.colorbar(mesh_2, ax=[ax_1, ax_2, ax_error])
plt.show()
```

[image: sharedcbar]

If you want better spacing you can try `constrained_layout`:

```
fig, (ax_1, ax_2, ax_error) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 6), 
                                           constrained_layout=True)
```

[image: Constrained_layout]

Constrained layout will also work for just one axes:

```
fig.colorbar(mesh_2, ax=ax_2)
```

[image: Oneaxes]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I've upvoted your answer. When I tried your code, I got an unexpected error saying that "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'constrained_layout' ". So I just google it and find this [official tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html). From the tutorial, I found that the keypoint is not in `constrained_layout`, but in `shrink`. I will post my answer later. Thanks again for your help.